# Two different data sources in a Weblogic server

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, weblogic12c

I have a Weblogic server configured in Eclipse with a local database as the data source.  When debugging issues it would be nice to be able to connect to the database the test group is using.  I thought I would be able to clone the default "myserver" in the default mydomain and create new data sources which point to the test groups database.  I've done this but now I'm attempting to figure out how to start this new server and deploy my application to it through Eclipse.

I don't really care how it works, I just need to be able to easily switch between the two data sources, either through the Weblogic admin console or through eclipse via multiple servers. Being able to clone the current server would be nice since it's configuration is rather complex or just switch the sources out.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can have multiple `Data Sources` set up in your weblogic console, and when you wanna change to another data source just change in your applications `weblogic.xml` to the the relevant `jndi-name`

Comment: Can't you just modify the data source; or have two and switch which is associated with the server?

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI name must be different, because it connects through the JNDI name Every  data source should have unique JNDI name.